# Moving the dropdown arrow inline in navbar

Tags: css, r, shiny, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar in a R shiny application I am building and I need to move the dropdown arrow inline instead of under the menu.

[image: navbar]

Is it something to do with the navbar toggle?

[image]

Comment: Please give us the complete code or better, a working demo. use Jsfiddle or the stackoverflow run code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would show how to do it with your current code but since there isn't any I put together an example for you.

I use absolute positioning to place the `:after` element inside of the nav-item that is the parent class. Note the parent class needs relative positioning to keep the absolute positioned children inside of the parent.

I use `top:50%;` to bring the icon down to the middle of the parent container but it is always too low so I add `transform:translateY(-50%)`. That will pull up the icon 50% of it's own height to make it dead center.

I hope this was helpful :)

```css
.navbar{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
}

.nav-item{
  flex:1 1 20%;
  position:relative;
  background-color:black;
  padding:1em;
  color:white;
}

.nav-item:after{
  content:'>';
  font-size:14px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:1em;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-item">
    Item 1
  </div><!-- nav-item -->
    <div class="nav-item">
    Item 2
  </div><!-- nav-item -->
    <div class="nav-item">
    Item 3
  </div><!-- nav-item -->
      <div class="nav-item">
    Item 4
  </div><!-- nav-item -->
</div><!--navbar -->
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm running through the bootstrap css to find the right nav item. Here is the code I am using: [bootstrap.css](https://bootswatch.com/4/united/bootstrap.css)

Comment: I'm not going to go through all of your css. sorry! Heres an article that might help you get better answer in the future: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/